# What is the fastest way to increase the value of a variable until it matches the value of another variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, logic, matching

I have a code that is increasing the value of a variable 'x' by 0.01 and do some calculations until it matches the value of another variable 'y'. While "X" is increasing, "y" is decreasing not linearly.

What would the best logic to find the value where 'x' and 'y' are the same or the closest? Increasing 'x' by 0.01 is doing the job, but as I'm really noob, I guess there is a clever way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check `x >= y` every time `x` is increased.

Comment: Brute force is the way to go

Comment: Figure out the rate `y` is decreasing and equate them mathematically.

Comment: I agree with @A.J.Uppal this is a mathematical problem. Unless you're unable to work it out mathematically, then you'd have to brute force it. Very broadly something like `while(calcX() <= calcY())`

Comment: Isn't it that OP already has a "brute force" loop, they're increasing `x` and doing some calculations with it until `x` is equal to `y` or close ..?

Comment: without seeing code the answer is a pineapple

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, then any of the root-finding algorithms should work.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to find an `x` such that `f(x) = y` for a constant `y`, and `f(x)` is non-linear but has no other inputs. Is this correct?

Let us further assume that `f(x)` is strictly increasing or decreasing (that is: it does not wiggle up and down and cross `y` at several `x`s). Then, you can use a standard binary search to find the single intercept:

1. find values

   - `x_lo` such that `f(x_lo) < y`
   - `x_hi` such that `f(x_hi) > y`
2. look at the midpoint `m = (x_hi + x_lo) / 2`.

   - if `f(m) < y`, use `x_lo = m`, and repeat this step
   - if `f(m) > y`, use `x_hi = m`, and repeat this step
   - if `f(m) == y`, or it is close enough for your needs, you have finished!

A simple way to find initial values for `x_hi` and `x_lo` that is to test `f(any)` value, and assign `x_hi=any` or `x_lo=any` depending on whether it is larger or
smaller than `y`. Once you have one extreme, you can quickly find the other by quickly increasing or decreasing it. Say we have `x_lo`, we can test with `x_hi = x_lo*(2^i)` for `i=1, 2, 3, ...`, with `^` representing exponentiation.

If `f(x)` crosses `y` at several points, this does not work - because it can skip right over the important `x` in step 2.